# Using arrow functions with .call()? "This" varies based on if in devtools or iojs locally? Should one avoid using arrows with .call?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've been running the below code and I notice that when running in devtools, obj.hi = 'default', while when running with iojs 3.3.1 with harmony arrow functions as an arg on my machine, obj.hi = 'foo'. "This" is the window when in devtools, while "this" is the object in iojs. Is it generally good practice to avoid using arrows with .call to avoid this?

```
'use strict'

let obj = {
   hi: "default"
}

let foobar = () => {
    console.log(this)
   this.hi = "foo"
}

foobar.call(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Why are you using iojs??!?!?!?!

Comment: Io.js is definitely wrong here. You probably should drop it and get a recent node install.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a problem with iojs... I swapped to node 6.2.0 and it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: These features were being flags for a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

See [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on MDN:

> Since this is already bound lexically, invoking an arrow function
>   through the call() or apply() methods can only pass in arguments, but
>   has no effect on this:

So you can use `call` and `apply` with arrow functions, but you can't influence their `this` value: they take `this` from the containing scope. The fact that you can dynamically change `this` with io.js just indicates that it is broken with regards to this part of the specification.

Comment: Why does iojs + harmony functions succeed in grabbing the obj as this then? Is it lexically grabbing it (this is the object closest in lexical scope when running locally, while the window is the object closest for chrome)? I don't get why there is a difference between devtools and iojs + harmony...

Comment: Edited. I wouldn't phrase failing to meet the specification as success :-)